# Cannot use ScrollView layout inside the SlidingUpPanelLayout Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-scrollview

I used this library in my code. Basically I have a a ScrollView on the SlidingUp panel layout. The code is as below:

```
<cheesebaron.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom">
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/HomeFrameLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/slidingPanelScrollView"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="false">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent">
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/cardHolderRelativeLayout"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_width="380dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:padding="10dp">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                                android:layout_height="250dp"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:background="#FF0000"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                                android:layout_height="250dp"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:background="#00FF00"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                                android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1" />
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                                android:layout_height="250dp"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:background="#0000FF"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                                android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout2" />
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                                android:layout_height="250dp"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:background="#0000FF"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                                android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout2" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </cheesebaron.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

What I want to achieve is that, if the SlidingUpPanelLayout is expanded, user should be able to scroll the ScrollView. If the ScrollView is scrolled to its top (user scroll down on their phone) and user keep scrolling down, the SlidingUpPanelLayout should collapsed.

I implement the following code:

_slidingUpPanelLayout.NestedScrollingEnabled = true;

```
        _scrollView.ViewTreeObserver.ScrollChanged += (sender, e) => 
        {
            var y = _scrollView.ScrollY;
            if (y < -20)
            {
                _slidingUpPanelLayout.SlidingEnabled = true;
            } 

        };

        _slidingUpPanelLayout.PanelExpanded += (sender, args) => 
        {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
            _cardHolderRelativeLayout.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

            _slidingUpPanelLayout.SlidingEnabled = false;
        };
```

Basically I set SlidingEnable to true/false to change the scroll event listener.

However, there is a problem with the ScrollView. It only triggers when the ScrollView is scrolled up and then scrolled down.

Anyway, I don't think my approach is a good approach. Any suggestion? Also, when I look at the AndroidSlidingUpPanel library on Android native, it seems like it supports ScrollView inside SlidingUpPanelLayout out-of-box already. Not sure if I am correct or not.

I am also not sure if there is anything to do with NestedScrollingEnabled = true for the SlidingUp panel or not, but I saw quite few recommendations on Stackoverflow.

Cheers,

Answer (score -1):

Try to using nestedScrollview instead of scrollview

```
NestedScrollView scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById (R.id.scrollView);
scrollView.setFillViewport (true);
```

Comment: It does not work. I tried it already. Please have a look at my code rather than providing a random theory code in like that. I already tried few methods before asking.